# How to call a function when its name is a string

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this:

```
    angular.module("angular-table").directive("atPagination", [
    function() {
      return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: false,
        replace: true,
        template: paginationTemplate,
        link: function($scope, $element, $attributes) {

          //The function name
          let fn = '$scope.' +  $attributes.getDataFn;
          console.log($scope.$eval(fn),$attributes,$attributes.getDataFn, "$eval", fn); 
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling the function using `$scope.$eval` in the console(last line). But the function is not getting called.

I am trying to change this library I am using for table and pagination. I am trying to pass a function from my controller into its directive so that it gets called when next is clicked in the pagination.

I can't pass the function the regular way because the `scope` is false and I don't want to change it. So I am passing it like this

```
 <at-pagination at-config="tableConfig" 
     get-data-fn="getPaginatedData()" at-list="personnelsdata">
 </at-pagination>
```

I am trying to call the function using `$eval` but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: false,
    template: paginationTemplate,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      //The function name
      ̶l̶e̶t̶ ̶f̶n̶ ̶=̶ ̶'̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶'̶ ̶+̶ ̶ ̶$̶a̶t̶t̶r̶i̶b̶u̶t̶e̶s̶.̶g̶e̶t̶D̶a̶t̶a̶F̶n̶;̶
      let fn = attrs.getDataFn;
      console.log(scope.$eval(fn)); 
    }
})
```

The `scope.$eval` method evaluates an AngularJS function, not a JavaScript function.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - AngularJS Expressions vs. JavaScript Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#angularjs-expressions-vs-javascript-expressions)
- [AngularJS scope API Reference - $eval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval)